# How do I move h/c water from garage to the other side of the wall.

Tags: dryer, washer

We just bought our first home and the previous owners had the washer/dryer in the garage. We would like to move the washer/dryer into a large closet just on the other side of the wall from where they are located now. It looks like someone in the past may have had the setup the way we want because there is a dryer vent/hole (which is covered at the moment) as well as a higher than normal volt outlet, not sure what it is referred to. 
As one can read I dont know the correct verbiage when it comes to hand man work. I am learning as I go. 
Please help with any information on what needs to be done before the washer and dryer arrive!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The new hookup location will need:

**For Washer**

1. Cold water hose connection with shut off valve
2. Hot water hose connection with shut off valve
3. Drain line riser connection that comes up to a level similar to the top of the washer tub
4. Normal AC Line voltage outlet for the washer to plug into

**For Dryer**

1. Dryer vent connection
2. For Electric Dryer - A 220/240VAC high current outlet (commonly 30A)
3. a) For Gas Dryer - Natural gas connection with shut off valve
4. b) For Gas Dryer - Normal AC Line voltage outlet for the dryer to plug into

Comment: Note that many jurisdictions require an automatic shut off valve for the water (in case of a burst pipe) and a GFCI outlet for the power (in case of a ground fault).

Comment: Does code determine what side hot and cold should be on?  Do they need to have red and blue handles?  I know Hot left, cold right is typical.

Answer (score 0):

Plastic pipe also known a PEX would be an easy way to get water across to new location. As far as the elevation of receptecal no problem as long as the cord will reach.